# Facebook access token expiration how to get extended? perl desktop app

Tags: facebook, perl, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth

I made a Perl script for Facebook but it doesn't work after a period of time, or if I log out.  I think this is due to the access token expiring.

Could somebody help me to extend the expiration of the token?

Answer (score 5):

[First, look here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/)

and you can find something similar:

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
     client_id=APP_ID&
     client_secret=APP_SECRET&
     grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
     fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

it will return token.

But! be sure, that you call this method twice. First time it return `2h expiring` token.
Not sure now what they do with this.

Comment: Could you put some example how to implement it in my application?And how to call it 2 times? oO

Comment: first time you call it for `2h` access_token, second time (when you have `2h` access_token, you call it with this token to get normal access_token)