# How to get extended access token for perl app?

Tags: facebook, oauth-2.0

I found this on facebook site, but what I need to do with this to get extended access token?

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Comment: Hmm, I notice this question is a follow-on to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14967031/facebook-access-token-expiration-how-to-get-extended-perl-desktop-app . Would it not be better to keep it all in the same question?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have an access token from a successful OAuth interaction, just invoke this url, replacing EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN with the token you got from the initial OAUth, and client_id and client_secret with the App ID and the App secret for your app (see https://developers.facebook.com/apps).  You will get back json containing an extended token.

An OAuth interaction in this context prompts the user to give your app permission to access their profile data, or act with certain permissions on behalf of the user.  In facebook, if you redirect the users browser to

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?
    client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
    &redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URL
    &state=YOUR_STATE_VALUE
    &scope=COMMA_SEPARATED_LIST_OF_PERMISSION_NAMES
```

where scope is something like publish_stream,read_friendlists, the user will see a dialog saying "APP X is requesting permission to write to your wall and read your friends lists.  Permit or Deny".  If the user permits, you will get json posted to YOUR_REDIRECT_URL, which will contain an access token.  This is the EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN.

Have a look at the facebook oauth docs here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/

Comment: What is OAuth interaction?